# BMI Calculation Program

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have created an application to calculate BMI. Basically, here is how I'd like the application to work and wrote below so far:

- You just enter your height in inches and enter weight in pounds.
- The application will calculate your BMI, then tell you whether you are underweight, normal, obese, or overweight.
- In case you enter a non-positive value for either height or weight, the program will show you an error message that "Invalid input. Enter a positive number.", and it will highlight the boxes that you need to fix/enter a valid value.

**I have encountered 2 problems.**

- I can get the program to show the BMI result, but currently I don't know how to write to get the program to show whether the user is underweight, normal, obese, or overweight.
  If BMI < 18.5 then underweight, BMI >= 18.5 and <=24.99 then normal, BMI > 25 and <=29.99 then obese, and BMI > 30 then overweight.
- I would like to show the error (that tells user to enter positive values, not missing or negative values) as messages below the "Calculate BMI" button, not as an alert like "This page says - Invalid input for weight, enter a non-negative number." In other words, I would like to keep the same message but not using "alert" method.

How may I fix these problems please? I have attached both my HTML and my CSS codes below.

Thank you so much!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>BMI Calculation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bmi.css">

</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h2>Body Mass Index Calculation Application</h2>

        <label for="boxHeight">Enter height in inches:</label>
        <input type='text' id='boxHeight'/><br>

        <label for="boxWeight">Enter weight in pounds:</label>
        <input type='text' id='boxWeight'/><br>

        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">

        <div class="results"></div>

    </main>     
    <script>
        var processEntries = function() {   

             var heightInputBox = document.getElementById("boxHeight");
             var weightInputBox = document.getElementById("boxWeight");
             var outputBMI = document.querySelectorAll("div.results");

             outputBMI[0].textContent = "";
             heightInputBox.className = "";
             weightInputBox.className = "";

             console.log(heightInputBox.getAttribute('class'));

            ///get user input from input box "boxHeight" by using value property, 
            //which return user input as a string               
            //step1.1:get height input and convert height to a number
            var height = heightInputBox.value;
            height = parseFloat(height);

            //step1.2:get weight input and convert weight to a number
            var weight = weightInputBox.value;
            weight = parseFloat(weight);

            var valid = true;           
            if (isNaN(height)||height <0) {
                alert("Invalid input for height, enter a non-negative number.");
                heightInputBox.className = "error";
                valid = false;
            } 

            if (isNaN(weight)||weight <0) {
                alert("Invalid input for weight, enter a non-negative number.");
                weightInputBox.setAttribute('class', "error");
                valid = false;
            }

            if (valid)          //calculate BMI
            {
                outputBMI[0].textContent  ="Your BMI is: " + (703 * weight / (height*height)).toFixed(1);
            if (outputBMI[0]<18.5) outputBMI[0].textContent = "Your BMI indicates that you are underweight.";
            if (outputBMI[0]>=18.5 && outputBMI[0]<=24.99) document.getElementById("result").value = "Normal";
            if (outputBMI[0]>=25 && outputBMI[0]<=29.99) document.getElementById("result").value = "Obese";
            if (outputBMI[0]>30) document.getElementById("result").value = "Overweight";
            }
        };

        //add js code here to handler click event, and make the height input box be focused after the page is opened in web browser
        document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = processEntries;

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code also, if you need it:

```
article, aside, figure, footer, header, main, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: url('BMI.jpg') center center fixed;

    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    border: 3px solid blue;

}
html {
    background-color: #eee;
}
main {
    padding: 0 2em 1em;
    margin: 2em;
    background-color: white;

}
h2 {
    color: blue;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 12em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}

div {
    width: 24em;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: .5em;   
    font-size: 20px;

}

input {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;

}
input.error {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    border: 2px solid #fe9772;
}
```

Comment: Your question is kind of broad, and you haven't actually listed any specific problems. A description of what you want the program to do isn't a "problem", it's a requirement. What problems are you encountering when trying to implement those requirements? Take a look at [ask].

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think it would be better for me to include of what I expect out of the program - I actually listed the problems I encountered below the description.

Comment: Your recent edit removed some code that looked like your attempts at achieving what you want -- leaving those in would actually be more helpful for people to see where you are having issues.

Comment: Thank you! I will add those back in - because I just realized that my code is fatally wrong - but I will add them back now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to rework on your code. But the bottom line is that you need to remember that a classSelector (in your case results) always return an array. Switch to an Id if you're using an unique dom

```js
var processEntries = function() {   

             var heightInputBox = document.getElementById("boxHeight");
             var weightInputBox = document.getElementById("boxWeight");
             var resultElm = document.getElementById("result");

             resultElm.textContent = "";
             heightInputBox.className = "";
             weightInputBox.className = "";

             console.log(heightInputBox.getAttribute('class'));

            ///get user input from input box "boxHeight" by using value property, 
            //which return user input as a string               
            //step1.1:get height input and convert height to a number
            var height = heightInputBox.value;
            height = parseFloat(height);

            //step1.2:get weight input and convert weight to a number
            var weight = weightInputBox.value;
            weight = parseFloat(weight);

            var valid = true;           
            if (isNaN(height)||height <0) {
                alert("Invalid input for height, enter a non-negative number.");
                heightInputBox.className = "error";
                valid = false;
            } 

            if (isNaN(weight)||weight <0) {
                alert("Invalid input for weight, enter a non-negative number.");
                weightInputBox.setAttribute('class', "error");
                valid = false;
            }
            var bmi = 703 * weight / (height** 2)
            if (valid)          //calculate BMI
            {
                resultElm.textContent  ="Your BMI is: " + (bmi).toFixed(1);
                if (bmi<18.5) resultElm.textContent += " Your BMI indicates that you are underweight.";
                if (bmi>=18.5 && bmi<=25) resultElm.textContent += " Your BMI indicates that you are Normal.";
                if (bmi>=25 && bmi<=30)resultElm.textContent += " Your BMI indicates that you are Obese.";
                if (bmi>30) resultElm.textContent += " Your BMI indicates that you are Overweight";
            }
        };

        //add js code here to handler click event, and make the height input box be focused after the page is opened in web browser
        document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = processEntries;
```

```css
article, aside, figure, footer, header, main, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: url('BMI.jpg') center center fixed;

    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    border: 3px solid blue;

}
html {
    background-color: #eee;
}
main {
    padding: 0 2em 1em;
    margin: 2em;
    background-color: white;

}
h2 {
    color: blue;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 12em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}

div {
    width: 24em;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: .5em;   
    font-size: 20px;

}

input {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;

}
input.error {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    border: 2px solid #fe9772;
    }
```

```html
<main>
        <h2>Body Mass Index Calculation Application</h2>

        <label for="boxHeight">Enter height in inches:</label>
        <input type='text' id='boxHeight'/><br>

        <label for="boxWeight">Enter weight in pounds:</label>
        <input type='text' id='boxWeight'/><br>

        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">

        <div id="result"></div>

    </main>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes I definitely need some work - I just recently changed major and this is already tough haha! I hope it gets better with time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already has a good and valid answer.

The following is simply the result of me playing around with the fiddle, trying to shorten it and make it more "responsive".

I removed the calculate button and use `eval()` now to tolerantly convert and calculate the input fields' values.

```js
const qs=s=>document.querySelector(s);
evl=s=>{var v='', el=qs(s);
 try{v=eval(el.value)||''} catch(er){v=''}
 el.nextElementSibling.innerText=(v?'='+v.toFixed(2):v);
 return v
}
var scale=[[18.5,"underweight"],
 [25,"normal"],[30,"obese"],
 [31,"seriously overweight"]];
 
qs("body").addEventListener("keyup",ev=>{if(ev.target.type!='text') return;
 var txt, height=evl("#boxHeight"), weight=evl("#boxWeight");
 if (height>0 && weight>0){
   BMI=703*weight/(height*height);
   scale.every(sc=>(txt=sc[1],BMI>sc[0])); 
   txt='Your BMI of '+BMI.toFixed(1)+" indicates<br>that you are "+txt+".";
 } else txt='';
 qs("#result").innerHTML=txt
 
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: url('BMI.jpg') center center fixed;

    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    border: 3px solid blue;

}
html {
    background-color: #eee;
}
main {
    padding: 0 2em 1em;
    margin: 2em;
    background-color: white;
}
h2 {
    color: blue;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 12em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}
div {
    width: 24em;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: .5em;   
    font-size: 20px;
}

input {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;

}
span {margin-left:20px;
      font-size:1.5ex;}
```

```html
<main>
        <h2>Body Mass Index Calculation Application</h2>

        <label for="boxHeight">Enter height in inches:</label>
        <input type='text' id='boxHeight' placeholder="value or formula"/><span id="one"></span><br>

        <label for="boxWeight">Enter weight in pounds:</label>
        <input type='text' id='boxWeight' placeholder="value or formula"/><span id="two"></span><br>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </main>
```

Comment: This code is great too! Thank you for adding to my learning process!

Comment: Glad to hear! I did it mainly to "educate myself", but if anyone else likes it, it is even better! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I have edited my code several times and this is a version that I think is worth sharing. I know that there are still quite some edits to do - but here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>BMI Calculation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bmi.css">

</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h2>Body Mass Index Calculation Application</h2>

        <label for="boxHeight">Enter height in inches:</label>
        <input type='text' id='boxHeight'/><br>

        <label for="boxWeight">Enter weight in pounds:</label>
        <input type='text' id='boxWeight'/><br>

        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">

        <div class="results"></div>

    </main>     
    <script>
        var processEntries = function() {   

             var heightInputBox = document.getElementById("boxHeight");
             var weightInputBox = document.getElementById("boxWeight");
             var outputBMI = document.querySelectorAll("div.results");

             outputBMI[0].textContent = "";
             heightInputBox.className = "";
             weightInputBox.className = "";

             console.log(heightInputBox.getAttribute('class'));

            var height = heightInputBox.value;
            height = parseFloat(height);

            var weight = weightInputBox.value;
            weight = parseFloat(weight);

            var valid = true;           
            if (isNaN(height)||height <0 || height != parseInt(height, 10)) {
                outputBMI[0].textContent +=" Invalid input for height, enter a non-negative number.";
                heightInputBox.className = "error";
                valid = false;
            } 

            if (isNaN(weight)||weight <0 || weight != parseInt(weight, 10)) {
                outputBMI[0].textContent +=" Invalid input for weight, enter a non-negative number.";
                weightInputBox.setAttribute('class', "error");
                valid = false;
            }

            if (valid)
            {
                outputBMI[0].textContent  ="Your BMI is: " + (703 * weight / (height*height)).toFixed(1);

                //This is just for my trial and learning process. =)
                var bmi = (703 * weight / (height*height)).toFixed(1);
                if (bmi<18.5) outputBMI[0].textContent += " Your BMI indicates that you are underweight.";
                if (bmi>=18.5 && bmi<=25) outputBMI[0].textContent += "Your BMI indicates that you are normal.";
                if (bmi>25 && bmi<=30) outputBMI[0].textContent += "Your BMI indicates that you are obsese.";
                if (bmi>30) outputBMI[0].textContent += "Your BMI indicates that you are overweight.";
            }
        };

       //handler button click event 
        document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = processEntries;

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Steve, welcome to SO! Thanks for sharing your code. Have you heard of [stack snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? These are bits of runnable code you can include into your post. My post for example has such a snippet in it. It makes it easier for everyone to undestand and play around with the code. If you like you can still edit your own post and turn the code into a runnable snippet.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you for your suggestion. I will definitely use it next time.